# Encodings and process names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, encoding

I'm facing a weird, really weird, behavior in the process name when shell script file encodings are different.

The scenario is the folowing:

two files
- caller.sh (ASCII text)
- executor.sh (UTF-8 Unicode text)

```
# caller.sh
#!/bin/bash

/soft/executer.sh &
sleep 60
```

After executing "caller.sh &", the "ps" command return both process named as "caller.sh":

```
PID   TTY      TIME     CMD
19566 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
22699 pts/7    00:00:00 caller.sh
22690 pts/7    00:00:00 caller.sh
22694 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
```

But if a change the "caller.sh" encoding to "Bourne-Again shell script text executable" (saving in a windows box and transfered to linux) the command ps starts to show properly:

```
PID   TTY      TIME     CMD
19566 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
22689 pts/7    00:00:00 caller.sh
22694 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
22690 pts/7    00:00:00 executer.sh
```

Could someone explain that relation between encodings and process names/bashs?

p.s: dos2unix doesn't solve the issue!

Thanks

Comment: It's not `!#/bin/bash`, but `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Sorry, disregard that .. it's a typo

Comment: How does `executor.sh` receive a smaller PID than `caller.sh` if it is called from `caller.sh`? It looks like 22685 is a separate instance run by itself, not a child process of an instance of `caller.sh`.

Comment: ok, I've created that scenario manually and I put a smaller PID by mistake. Disregard that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason why it's happening. Actually is not because of encoding but because of the comment script has before the bash interpreter.

```
# test script
#!/bin/bash
...
```

I just removed it and everything start showing up ok :/

Does someone knows the reason why it happens?

Comment: When the system exec's a file, it checks the *first two* bytes of the file to see if they're "#!", and if they are it uses what follows as an interpreter to run the file as a script. If those characters are later in the file, they do no good at all. bash has a fallback mode where if the regular exec fails (as it will in this case), bash runs it as a bash script and hopes that's at least close, but it doesn't set everything up quite normally...

Comment: please move this "answer" to your question. You're still asking a question. Good luck to all.